# Why does a function that defines values via string in unity indicate the error " the index was out of range."?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing code for a quiz game. I can't understand why the "index was out of range" error appears in Unity itself.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7XRT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVKkM.png)

Comment: Welcome Сергей Мамонов. Please you can add the code with {} for better understand of the question.

Comment: Please read [ask] then edit the question